# Tablespace is missing for table after MySQL restart

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a Laravel app hosted on EC2 on AWS with MySQL database. After preforming a MySQL restart, we started to get this error "Tablespace is missing for table"
We've checked the folders that stores the tablespace, but the files were missing.
What can we do to recover the tablespace files?
Note: unfortunately the developers didn't take backups since long ago... So using the backup won't work.

Comment: Obviously the database wasn't very important, if no backups were made. I suppose you have no binary logs either, or a replica. Does this error occur for all tables, or just a subset of them?

Comment: We have many tables, only 4 tablespace files found and the ibdata1.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you stored the databases on instance storage and then restarted the EC2 instance?

Comment: I'm very sorry to hear this news. I too made a catastrophic data-loss mistake once. I've been a real demon about backups ever since. You *will* get through this.

Comment: The developer restarted the MySQL only, and for some reason most of the files are missing except ibdata1, log 1 and 2 and some ibd files for some tables.